# External ssh not working (port already forwarded)

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm setting up my first home server from an old pc. I've installed Ubuntu Server 15.10.
I've been trying and doing some research but I couldn't make the SSH work from an external computer, it always returns "Connection refused"

It works fine if I try from a LAN computer.
I've installed no-ip in order to get an easier address.
Regarding port forwarding, I have changed the port and I did the port forwarding from the router's webpage (192.168.1.1). I've checked in a website and it says my port is open.

The server is connected via ethernet from the router.
I have 4 computers connected to my router. Since my external IP is the same from all computers, how does the ssh knows which computer to connect? How can I know to which computer am I connecting?

I've realized how to know to which computer I am connecting to, but I still can't connect

Comment: Hey, can you share the information how you port forwarded then? (The question regarding choosing the right computer to connect triggers caution that you might have wrong port forwarding) Normally you should choose an IP (your server) and port to forward as a specific port.

Comment: When you configure your router for forward the port , the router then knows which of the 4 computers to send to. It sounds as if you have to configure your router and not ubuntu. Could be a problem with no-ip .

Comment: @PauliusŠukys This is what I did on my router's webpage: `Customer  3737  3737  TCP  3737  3737  192.168.1.8  ppp0` and `Customer  3737  3737  TCP  3737  3737  192.168.1.8  ppp1` Being it Server name - Inicial External Port -  External Final Port - Protocol - Internal Inicial Port - External Inicial Port - Server's IP - WAN Interface

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've also checked without using no-ip, I mean with my external IP and it's still not working

Comment: Hard to tell from what little you have posted. As it works on your LAN, my best guess is that you need to configure your router.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen had configured my router opening the port. I have checked in http://ping.eu/port-chk/ and it says my port is open. I have also done `sudo ufw allow 3737` and it's still not working

Comment: Well, if it works on your LAN , then it is not an Ubuntu / Server problem. Either you have the wrong public IP, your router is not configured properly, or your ISP is blocking the port. Can you ping your public IP?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This is what I get from www.canyouseeme.org is `Success: I can see your service on my_public_ip on port (3737)
Your ISP is not blocking port 3737` and yes, I can ping my public IP

Comment: so from what you posted, your router is not forwarding to the correct machine. Are you using a static ip on your LAN ? Check the server IP and make sure the router is forwarding the correct local ip (LAN)

Answer (score 0):

Does your router support DMZ network. I recently set up my webserver on my home router. And instead of port forwarding, I used my servers static ip in the DMZ zone. This way my server is connected to my public ip. And i can ssh from outside using the public IP too. Just make sure that using DMZ exposes the server to outside world so dont forget to install a firewall (i use shorewall) and just open ports you want. For ssh open 22.
Thats it. Regarding port forwarding i guess you'll get good suggestions from other community members.
If you have any questions regarding ssh to server iin DMZ of your router. Shoot here..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems my router does support DMZ. However, I'll try  with port forwarding since it seems safer. If I continue failing, I will do some research on DMZ to see what I am facing and I will give it a shot